# 'To be on' as 'in charge of' or 'to be working on'

Tags: meaning-in-context

I would to know if I could use 'to be on' to mean I'm working on something or I'm in charge of something. For example, could I replace 'I'm working on that issue' or 'I'm in charge of that issue' for 'I'm on that issue'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly in the way you are using it.  You can say, "I'm on the job" or "I'm on the project," but this means you are a part of the project. We have an English phrase you may be thinking of ..."I'm on it."  This means, "I will take care of it" or "I have everything under control."

For example, your co-worker says, "We still are having a problem with this part of the system."  You can say, I'm on it.  It should be fixed by tomorrow.